# New Custom App - Use a relational or non-relational database?

Tags: database, web-applications, relational-database, backend, non-relational-database

New developer here! Below is the basic process and data I need to store for my custom React app. What is the best database or backend to use for this situation? Would a relational database or non-relational database be better suited? Thanks in advance for the help!

**General Process:**

- Users from Group A Buy Item(s)
- Item Gets Assigned to Users from Group B
- Users from Group B can receive the items at different times

**Data Description:**

```
- Group A Users: 
    ○ These users can only Buy Items
    ○ Must store information like their name, address, phone, and when they became a user

- Group B Users:
    ○ These users can only Receive Items
    ○ Must store information like their name, address, when they were assigned the item, when they received the item, and when they became a user
    ○ In a rare case, a Group B User can become a Group A user after time

- Items:
    ○ Must store information like creation date, amount, user B who bought & received the item
    ○ Items are duplicated year to year (sometimes new items come in)
        § Ex: in 2019, the full item list is copied from 2018 and then bought by user A and user B receives
    ○ Group A & Group B Users can have 1:1 or 1:N relationship with Items

- History (Year over Year)
    ○ Group A User History: Need to see when Group A user buys items year over year
    ○ Item History: Need to see year to year which Group A Users bought items

- History (Current Year)
    ○ Group B User History: In the current year, need to see when a Group B User was assigned an item and when they received the item
    ○ Item History: In the current year, need to be able to see the status of the item (ready, assigned, or received)
```

Comment: I've flagged this question as `Needs improvement` - while I understand the reason to why you're asking the question you have, it'll lead to opinionated responses. You'll need to do some research on your own, so that you can ask more specific questions, instead of recommendations.

eg. an answer might suggest you do it in xml in lieu of a database.

Comment: Indeed. What do you mean by "best"/"better"? Cheapest? Fastest? Able to cope with a gigabyte/terabyte of data? etc? etc?